# The variable thedData is not defined. (-2753) AppleScript

Tags: applescript

The variable thedData is not defined. (-2753)
How to fix?

```
set default_path to "Users/mrvisuals/Desktop"
set nuntaNume to text returned of (display dialog "Nunta Nume:" default answer "")
set nuntaData to text returned of (display dialog "Nunta Data:" default answer "")
set folderpath to (choose folder with prompt "Select Folderul Nunti" default location default_path)
set newnuntaFolder to my newFold(nuntaNume, nuntaData, folderpath)
on newFold(theNume, theData, thefolder)
    set subNumeList to {"1.Steps Nunta", "2.STD", "3.TTD", "4.Album", "5.Blog", "6.Des"}
    set itemCount to count of subNumeList
    tell application "Finder"
        set newnuntaFolder to (make new folder at thefolder with properties {name:thedData & "_" & theNume})
        repeat with i from 1 to itemCount
            set thisFolder to make new folder at newnuntaFolder with properties {name:"" & item i of subNumeList}
            if item i of subNumeList contains "1.Steps Nunta" then
                make new folder at thisFolder with properties {name:"1.Pregatiri"}
                make new folder at thisFolder with properties {name:"2.First Look"}
                make new folder at thisFolder with properties {name:"3.Primarie"}
                make new folder at thisFolder with properties {name:"4.Biserica"}
                make new folder at thisFolder with properties {name:"5.Sedinta"}
                make new folder at thisFolder with properties {name:"6.Sala"}
            end if
        end repeat
    end tell
end newFold
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your handler defines the parameter as theData:

```
on newFold(theNume, theData, thefolder)
```

but your handler later refers to it as thedData:

```
set newnuntaFolder to (make new folder at thefolder with properties {name:thedData & "_" & theme})
```

In that line, you need to change thedData to theData

Comment: Work,but i did something wrong.I want to have the name what we set in this line: 'set nuntaNume to text returned of (display dialog "Nunta Nume:" default answer "")' to contain ALL my folders and subfolders after the name.Example: 1.Steps Nunta Name,2.STD Name.......etc.

Comment: Fix all my probleme. Put this line and i have the name in all folders: 'set thisFolder to make new folder at newnuntaFolder with properties {name:"" & item i of subNumeList & " " & theNume}'